# What does comma mean after javascript object declaration?

Tags: javascript, notation

Let's take some javascript code from vk.com

```
var stManager = {

   //some long code with methods and properties...

}, __stm = stManager;
```

Why do we need last line in this code? Why duplicate stManager one more time?

Comment: You're just declaring and initializing another variable (_stm) with the same value as stManager (hence making a copy of it) ... you may need the original value to make future value comparisons while keeping the original.

Comment: You edited the question and now it changed the entire context.....you might need a copy of `stManager`...hence you are using it.

Comment: Good job completely changing what this question is about.

Comment: Thank you for answers. Main thing is to make everything clear. Even if it seems to be stupid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you are declaring another variable. Just a different notation. It is the same as:

```
var stManager = {};
var _stm = stManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring and initializing multiple variables with single 'var' thats it...

```
var x=1,y=2;
```